# pushing a large cloned repo to github is failing (8gb) - fatal the remote hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, github, git-svn

As part of a migration process I want to migrate an old svn repo to github. It's important to keep the history from this old repo and not overwrite anything (so I do not want to force push). A newly created repo in GitHub exists and it contains no files that will clash with the locally migrated repo. However, when I attempt to push the repo I get a "fatal the remote hung up unexpectedly" error and nothing is pushed each time I try to push the repository.

I should add that in my research to solving this problem I have tried the following config setting changes:

```
git config --local core.packedGitLimit 1024m
git config --local pack.window 1
git config --local http.version HTTP/1.1
git config --local core.packedGitWindowSize 1024m
git config --local pack.deltaCacheSize 2047m
git config --local pack.packSizeLimit 2047m
git config --local pack.windowMemory 2047m
git config --local http.postBuffer 524288000
git config --local core.compression 0
```

All of which still result in the following error

```
error: RPC failed; HTTP 502 curl 55 OpenSSL SSL_write: Connection was reset, errno 10054
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Finally, It should be noted that when I took a subsection of the project (100mb) and pushed that all was fine and no error was returned, however, unless there is a way to properly partially push a repo until the entire repo is pushed then this is not a preferred approach for me to solve the problem.